# catchError() sets currentBuild.currentResult when it should only set the stageResult

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Parallel') {
      parallel {
        stage('Non-critical stage') {
          steps {
            script {
              // Other steps...
              if (/*some error condition*/) {
                catchError(buildResult: null, stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
                  // Fail only the stage, but leave the buildResult as is
                  error("Error message")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage('critical stage') {
          steps {
            // a different stage that really matters
          }
        }
      }
      post {
        always {
          script {
            if (currentBuild.currentResult != 'SUCCESS') {
              // When the Non-critical stage fails, the currentResult is UNSTABLE...
              // ...even though only the stageResult should have been set.
              // However, in the Jenkins UI the build result is SUCCESS
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the `Non-critical stage` the goal is to not let the build fail, when `some error condition` is met. But to only mark the stage as `UNSTABLE`. This works fine in Jenkins. The build result will be `SUCCESS`, even when the `Non-critical stage` is `UNSTABLE`. However, in the `post` block of the `Parallel` stage `currentBuild.currentResult` is set to `UNSTABLE`.

The `post` block is the last thing being executed. So I do not understand, how the build result can be shown as `SUCCESS` in Jenkins, when the currentResult is UNSTABLE in the last bit of Jenkinsfile code being executed.

Also when the `Non-critical stage` is skipped, `currentBuild.currentResult` is `SUCCESS` as expected. So the result being `UNSTABLE` is definitely caused by the `error()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my problem was, that the post stage was not directly in the scope of the pipeline block. And instead was directly in the `stage('Parallel')` block.

After moving the post block down like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Parallel') {
      parallel {
        stage('Non-critical stage') {
          steps {
            script {
              // Other steps...
              if (/*some error condition*/) {
                catchError(buildResult: null, stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
                  // Fail only the stage, but leave the buildResult as is
                  error("Error message")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        stage('critical stage') {
          steps {
            // a different stage that really matters
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always {
      script {
        if (currentBuild.currentResult != 'SUCCESS') {
          // Now the currentResult is 'SUCCESS'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the `currentBuild.currentResult` property correctly holds the value `SUCCESS`